# Is there a fortran equivalent of the matlab ismember function?

Tags: arrays, fortran, identity

Is there any fortran equivalent for the matlab function ismember?
In Matlab, my code is:

```
A = [1 0 0 1;0 1 1 0;0 1 1 0;];
B = [0 1 1 0;1 0 0 1;0 0 0 0;];

l = size(A,1);
for i = 1:l
    I = ismember(A,B(i,:),'rows');
    indx = find (I == 1)
end
```

The output of which is:

```
indx =

     2
     3


indx =

     1


indx =

  0×1 empty double column vector
```

Basically, what ismember does in my case is to check each row of Matrix B and verify if there is a matching row(s) in Matrix A.

**------------------------EDIT------------------------**

I wrote the following program in Fortran. The first part uses 2 do loops and gives the desired output. I wrote the second part to reduce the number of loops into one. However, the latter does not provide the desired output. Could you please tell me how the second part should be modified to give the desired result?

```
program ismember
  implicit none

  integer :: i,j, i_ind, ii
  integer, parameter :: N_lines = 5, N_columns = 3 
  integer, allocatable :: AA1(:,:),AA4(:,:)
  integer, allocatable :: indices(:)
  logical :: row_wanted2(N_lines)

  ! --------------------------- define the matrix AA1 ---------------------------!
  Allocate(AA1(N_lines,N_columns))
  do i=1,N_lines
     do j=1,N_columns
        AA1(i,j)= i + j 
     end do
  end do

  print*, 'AA1'
  do i = 1, N_lines
     write(*,"(1X,10I5)")  (AA1(i,j), j = 1, N_columns)
  end do

  ! --------------------------- define the matrix AA4 ---------------------------!
  Allocate(AA4(N_lines,N_columns))
  AA4(1,:) = AA1(5,:)
  AA4(3,:) = AA1(1,:)
  AA4(5,:) = AA1(3,:)
  AA4(2,:) = 0
  AA4(4,:) = 0  
  print*, 'AA4'
  do i = 1, N_lines
     write(*,"(1X,10I5)")  (AA4(i,j), j = 1, N_columns)
  end do

  ! --------------------------- ismember ---------------------------!
  print*, 'AA1 #lines', size(AA1,1)
  print*, 'AA1 #columns', size(AA1,2)

  row_wanted2 = .true.

  ! --------------------------- First part ---------------------------!  
  do i = 1, size(AA1,1)

     print*, i
     do ii = 1, size(AA4,1)
        if ( all( AA1(i,:) == AA4(ii,:) ) ) then
           print *, "AA1 and AA4 have same shape"
        else
           print *, "AA1 and AA4 have different shape"
        end if
     end do

  end do

  ! --------------------------- Second part ---------------------------!  
  do i = 1, size(AA1,1)
     
     indices = pack([(i_ind,i_ind=1,size(AA1,1))], all(AA1(i,:) == AA4(i_ind,:)) )
     if(size(indices).ge.1) then
        print*, 'indices', indices
        print*, 'we have a match'
     else
        row_wanted2(i) = .false.
        print*, 'we do not have a match'
     endif
     deallocate(indices)
     
  end do

  
end program ismember
```

Comment: There's nothing directly equivalent, you have to write it.

Comment: Thanks PierU for your reply. Could you please have a look at my fortran code and indicate to me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what can look like the equivalent of the Matlab function `ismember(a,b,'rows')` (I haven't tried compiling it, so there may be some bugs to correct):

```
function ismember_rows(a,b) result(c)
implicit none
real, intent(in) :: a(:,:), b(:)
logical, allocatable :: c(:)

integer :: n, m, i

n = size(a,1)
m = size(a,2)
if (size(b) /= m) stop "b size is wrong"

allocate( c(n) )
do i = 1, n
    c(i) = all( b(:) == a(i,:) )
end do

end function ismember_rows
```

It's pretty simple actually, just iterating on the rows of `a` and compare them to `b`. `c(i)` is true if all the elements of the ith row of `a` are equal to the elements of `b`.

Comment: Thank you PierU. This is similar to the first part of my code, is not it? It does the work. Could we use the intrinsic fortran function "pack" inside of the program avoiding the use of external functions and two do loops?

Comment: @user790082 It's probably similar, yes. I confess I didn't really dig into your code (if you have tested it and got the expected result, then all is ok). If you directly want to get the indeces, pack() is indeed the solution. There are also always to suppress one loop, but I find it more readable with an explicit loop.